# Adding a marker using the MapContainer.addMarker(Component, Coord) only works when screen is pressed

Tags: google-maps-markers, codenameone

I am making a project on InteliJ using codename one. I have a MapContainer and a marker that represents the user's location. I want to be able to just move this marker without refreshing all Markers so I am using the command `MapContainer.addMarker(Component, Coord)` but the marker only shows up in the right place when I press the map with my cursor.

I looked at this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/6BghRd4sFNM which linked me to this post https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2381. I used the command that it said `myMap.addMarker(myComponent, myCoord);`

Here is a video of the my app: https://streamable.com/my0q2. When the screen is not pressed, the marker shows up in different places as the map is dragged around, but when the map is pressed the button shows up in the right place. Why does this happen? If there is not a way to fix this, is there an alternate way that can let me add and remove a specific marker instead of clearing all map layers and re adding all of the markers? Thanks

Compiler errors:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx128m -Xss2m "-Dant.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant" "-Dant.library.dir=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-xz.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-jai.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-netrexx.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-swing.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-junitlauncher.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ant/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2 -logger com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.IdeaAntLogger2 -inputhandler com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.IdeaInputHandler -buildfile /Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/build.xml jar
build.xml
-pre-init
Created dir: /Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/lib/impl/native/android
Created dir: /Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/lib/impl/native/ios
Created dir: /Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/lib/impl/native/j2me
Created dir: /Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/lib/impl/native/javascript
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/googlemaps/InternalNativeMapsImpl.java (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at com.codename1.build.client.InstallLibsTask.unzip(InstallLibsTask.java:181)
    at com.codename1.build.client.InstallLibsTask.unzip(InstallLibsTask.java:127)
    at com.codename1.build.client.InstallLibsTask.execute(InstallLibsTask.java:82)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:834)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:190)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:274)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:31)
Generating GUI sources foo
No GUI Entries available
-init-private
-init-user
-init-project
-init-macrodef-property
-do-init
-post-init
-init-check
-init-ap-cmdline-properties
-init-macrodef-javac-with-processors
-init-macrodef-javac-without-processors
-init-macrodef-javac
-init-macrodef-test-impl
-init-macrodef-junit-init
-init-macrodef-junit-single
-init-test-properties
-init-macrodef-junit-batch
-init-macrodef-junit
-init-macrodef-junit-impl
-init-macrodef-testng
-init-macrodef-testng-impl
-init-macrodef-test
-init-macrodef-junit-debug
-init-macrodef-junit-debug-batch
-init-macrodef-junit-debug-impl
-init-macrodef-test-debug-junit
-init-macrodef-testng-debug
-init-macrodef-testng-debug-impl
-init-macrodef-test-debug-testng
-init-macrodef-test-debug
-init-debug-args
-init-macrodef-nbjpda
-init-macrodef-debug
-init-macrodef-java
-init-presetdef-jar
-init-ap-cmdline-supported
-init-ap-cmdline
init
-deps-jar-init
Deleting: /Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar
-warn-already-built-jar
Updating property file: /Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/build/built-jar.properties
-check-automatic-build
-clean-after-automatic-build
-verify-automatic-build
-pre-pre-compile
-cn1-compile-css
-pre-compile
Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
        code size and wider device support
Compiling 1 source file to /Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/build/tmp
Running javac...
/Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/src/litvak/ap/MyApplication.java:33: error: package com.sun.tools.javac.comp does not exist
import com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow;
                               ^
/Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/src/litvak/ap/MyApplication.java:34: error: package sun.jvm.hotspot.oops does not exist
import sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Mark;
                           ^
Note: /Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/src/litvak/ap/MyApplication.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors
/Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/build.xml:66: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:1133)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:834)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:190)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:274)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:31)
/Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/build.xml:66: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:1133)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:834)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:190)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:274)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:31)
/Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/build.xml:66: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:1133)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:834)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:190)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:274)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:31)

Ant build completed with 3 errors and 40 warnings in 4s at 2019-04-24 11:09
```

Comment: Is this on the simulator or on device?
Can you show a screenshot? 
Did you pass the JavaScript key when creating the `MapContainer`? Do you see warnings in the console?

Comment: This on the simulator. I am getting this error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codename1.googlemaps.InternalNativeMapsImpl" in the console and I can't send it as build because I get multiple compiler errors.

Comment: What are the compiler errors you're getting?
That exception generally means the cn1lib wasn't installed properly.

Comment: I put the error in my post.

Comment: Switch to text view and post the text https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-intellij-idea-ram.html

Comment: Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have serious compiler errors after refresh libs. Fix them and refresh again:

```
/Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/src/litvak/ap/MyApplication.java:33: error: package com.sun.tools.javac.comp does not exist
import com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow;
                               ^
/Users/Maxthesavage/IdeaProjects/ap/src/litvak/ap/MyApplication.java:34: error: package sun.jvm.hotspot.oops does not exist
import sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Mark;
```